# Android webview multitouch zoom not work in HVGA

Tags: android, webview

On galaxy S the zoom controls work on multitouch, but on HTC Legend, the same code doesnt work. What is the matter?

Answer (score 1):

There is something going on with the HTC legend and multitouch. see this -i agree, rather messy- link: http://www.htclegendforum.com/htc-legend-general-discussion/only-%27pinch-to-zoom%27-no-tual-touch-no-multi-touch/

As I understand it, the HTC legend supports only 'pinch to zoom', not real multitouch.

Answer (score 1):

Htc has done some changes in their webview implementation and that requires to call some API to make pinch to zoom working on those phones. Try following:

```
_webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        try {
            Method m = _webView.getClass().getMethod("enableMultiTouch",
                    null);
            if (m != null) {
                m.invoke(_webView, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Method m = _webView.getClass().getMethod(
                    "enableMultiTouchTextRelow", boolean.class);
            if (m != null) {
                m.invoke(_webView, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            Method m = _webView.getClass().getMethod(
                    "setIsCacheDrawBitmap", boolean.class);
            if (m != null) {
                m.invoke(_webView, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Must for HTC EVO to do text reflow after double tap
        try {
            Method m = _webView.getClass().getMethod("enableSmartZoom",
                    null);
            if (m != null) {
                m.invoke(_webView, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
```